# Node request handler restarting with stream

Tags: node.js, stream, youtube-dl

sorry for the kind of specific question, but I'm having a very strange issue and I'm not sure why it's happening.

I'm writing a Node application that takes a Youtube videoID and then streams the audio to the requester.  Here's the code.

```
router.get('/video/:videoId', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('requested ' + req.params.videoId);
  var filename = req.params.videoId + ".mp3";

  youtubeDL.exec(req.params.videoId, ['-x', '--audio-format', 'mp3', '-o', filename], {}, function(err, output) {
    if (err){
      res.send("bad request");
      return;
    }else{
      console.log("exec begin")
      res.setHeader("content-type", "audio/mp3");
      fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(res);
      fs.unlink(filename);
      console.log("exec end")
    }
  });
  console.log("router end");
});
```

The problem is that the request starts "looping" I guess is how I would describe it, and the request is invoked 3 times before stopping.

For example, here's the output for http://localhost:3000/resources/video/JCHTX_pgw6A

```
requested JCHTX_pgw6A
router end
[Long pause here]
exec begin
exec end
GET /resources/video/JCHTX_pgw6A 200 17396.280 ms - -
requested JCHTX_pgw6A
router end
[Long pause here]
exec begin
exec end
GET /resources/video/JCHTX_pgw6A 200 17550.309 ms - -
requested JCHTX_pgw6A
router end
[Long pause here]
exec begin
exec end
GET /resources/video/JCHTX_pgw6A 200 1645.932 ms - -
```

at which point it stops.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening or how to get additional information?  I'm totally stumped.

Comment: How is the request being made from the client?

Comment: I'm visiting http://localhost:3000/resources/video/JCHTX_pgw6A with my browser (Chrome), and the result is the browser media player, but the arrow is grayed out because it doesn't load.

Comment: Are there any messages in the Chrome developer console and/or any useful clues under the network tab for the video requests?

Comment: Nothing in the console, and as for the network tab I'm not entirely sure what I'm supposed to be looking for.  [It looks like this](http://imgur.com/k2yI4q6)

Comment: If you click on each request you should see details. In particular the first request has a type of "document" which doesn't seem right, but then seemingly gets the correct data the second time around. Check headers and body data to verify what's expected is being sent by the server.

Comment: Hi, again I'm not sure what I'm looking for, so I just took screenshots.  Nothing stands out to me in particular.

Also all the headers didn't fit into one window, so I did it in chunks.
[First Request](http://imgur.com/1VaFm8m)
[First Request Headers](http://imgur.com/X2KCmTp)
[Second Request](http://imgur.com/dK233Eb)
[Second Request Headers](http://imgur.com/yz5Ci6j)
[Third Request](http://imgur.com/OKoQwQZ)
[Third Request Headers](http://imgur.com/OKoQwQZ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the request method to POST and it stopped misbehaving.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `fs.unlink()` right after you *start* to stream the file, otherwise the file stops streaming to the client. Instead, either find a way to stream directly from youtube (a better solution IMHO as you would avoid hitting the disk) *or* at least wait until the file is done streaming before deleting it. For the latter that might look something like:

```
console.log("exec begin")
res.setHeader("content-type", "audio/mp3");
fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(res).on('finish', function() {
  fs.unlink(filename);
});
console.log("exec end")
```

or perhaps even better (waits for the file descriptor to actually close first):

```
console.log("exec begin")
res.setHeader("content-type", "audio/mp3");
fs.createReadStream(filename).on('close', function() {
  fs.unlink(filename);
}).pipe(res);
console.log("exec end")
```

Comment: So, I tried your solution, but the problem remained.  I also tried removing the unlink line entirely and the problem still persisted.  

Also, I found out that the request wasn't looping infinitely, but rather stopped after the third time.  I edited the question to reflect this.